# In react hooks web app, props is not getting correctly in component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the react hooks web, I have a component called NominatePerson, in that component if the `props.role` is not admin it should display text `Nomination View` and if its admin then it should display Dashboard. This is not happening, it always displays Dashboard. Could someone help me to resolve the issue ?

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [role, setRole] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const userEmail = localStorage.getItem("loginEmail");
        const res = await Axios.get(
          "http://localhost:8000/service/managenomineeaccess",
          { params: { userEmail } }
        );
        console.log(res.data[0][0].access, "rest.data");
        const data = res.data[0][0].access;
        setRole(data);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  const switchAdmin = (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={() => <Login role={role} />} />
      <ProtectedRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={DashboardLayout} />
      <ProtectedRoute exact path='/manageNominees' component={ManageNominees} />  
      <Route path='/nominatePerson' exact component={NominatePerson} />
      <Route path='/nominationView' exact component={NominationView} />

    </Switch>
  );
  const switchUser = (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
      <Route
        path='/nominatePerson'
        exact
        component={() => <NominatePerson role={role} />}
      />
      <Route
        path='/nominationView'
        exact
        component={() => <NominationView role={role} />}
      />
      <Route component={NominationView} />
      
    </Switch>
  );
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <GlobalStyles />
          {role === "admin" ? switchAdmin : switchUser}
        </ThemeProvider>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

NominatePerson

```
const NominatePerson = (props) => {

return (
<div className='leftNavItem'>
          <a>
            <Link
              to={props.role ? "/nominationView" : "/dashboard"}
              className='nav-link'
            >
              <b>{props.role ? "Nomination View" : "Dashboard"}</b>
            </Link>
          </a>
        </div>
)

}
```

server.js  // get service

```
app.get("/service/managenomineeaccess", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let userEmail = req.query.userEmail;
    let data = await sequelize.query(
      `SELECT access FROM devchoice.managenominees where email="${userEmail}";`
    );
    res.status(200).send(data);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ fail: e.message });
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Include your `console.log` too

Comment: Can you provide code sandbox? (or at least attach `package.json`)

Comment: @Shri Hari This  const data = res.data[0][0].access;` is getting undefined

Comment: Then what does `res.data` has?

Comment: throw your error from `catch` block to see if there's any exception

Comment: Doesn't have data.. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'access')
    at fetchData (App.js:44:1)

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: API response doesn't contain any items in the data array

Comment: Then there is a problem at the backend

Comment: I have added the back end service, the query is giving correct access, but it is not coming in front end

Comment: Try logging `data[0][0].access` from your controller before send response

Comment: use `const data = await sequelize.query("*****", { type: QueryTypes.SELECT } );`

Comment: Is your `userEmail` has data? It goes with the URL?

Comment: Yes it has data

Comment: ``const data = await sequelize.query(`SELECT access FROM devchoice.managenominees where email="${userEmail}";`,{ type: QueryTypes.SELECT } );``

Comment: Do you mean like above ?

Comment: Yeah. I meant this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248596/discussion-between-shri-hari-l-and-soccerway).